# Triquetra proportions and Golden Mean?

Tags: geometry, triangles, knot-theory, golden-ratio

I've been tinkering with drawings of Triquetras (triangular figures composed of three overlapping arcs), and wondering why this ancient symbol has appeared in so many cultures over so many ages.

It occurred me that perhaps some mathematical ratio gives this symbol its harmonious appearance.

I drew a triquetra using the Golden Ratio, i.e., 1.6108 : 1, or (sqrt(5) + 1)/2, and found that it is possible to incorporate this ratio in its construction. I've attached the figure below (apologies for its crude appearance), and it does seem to work:

[image: Triquetra using Golden Mean]

I'm just wondering if anyone else is familiar with the use of the Golden ratio in the construction of a triquetra, or if the inner triangle where the three lenses meet should be equilateral (i.e., form a Reuleaux triangle). The inner triangle of a triquetra based on the Golden ratio is not a Reuleaux triangle; rather, it is an isosceles triangle.

Any helpful comments would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Although a ratio *close* to $\varphi$ is often pleasing, it's an error, I think, to put too much stock in the *exact* value of $\varphi$. The figures are, typically, no less pleasing when the ratio is simply $5/3$ or $8/5$ or something like that.

Comment: Thank you for the note of caution. I was simply exploring the connections between mathematical ratios and geometric forms. I'm not putting too much stock in the fact that the Golden Ratio can be used when drawing a triquetra - 1.6 or 1.7 would probably work just as well. But using vector graphics, for example, it is more satisfying to draw a perfectly round circle than one that is 0.9 by 1.0, even though it will look something like a circle.

Comment: This knot, also known as the trefoil knot, or the overhand knot, is the simplest of all knots; take a look at the table at https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Knot_table That seems like the main reason it would appear so often across cultures.

One common way this knot appears as a design is in a two-component link, where the other component is a circle that weaves through the three lobes of the trefoil. That one seems to have a ratio that's far from the golden ratio.

Comment: Regarding ratios, there is a wide range of ratios that permit the construction of a triqueta. I'm curious what ratio would involve splitting each lune into two equal-area parts. I was messing with geogebra, and all I know is that this ratio is somewhere between 1.36 and 2.

Comment: Indeed there is a wide range of ratios that will permit the construction of a triqueta. And I didn't know the area where two circles overlap is called a “lune.”  I think the number of ratios that will permit the construction of a triquetra with an interweaving circle, often referred to as a Celtic Knot, is somewhat more limited than just constructing a triquetra itself.

Comment: In videos showing the construction of Celtic Knot using vector graphics, starting with three equal circles intersecting to form a Reuleaux triangle in the center, the overlap is done by what "looks right" to the trained eye. The same goes for calculating the size and placement the interweaving circle, as well as the thickness of the outlines. I just found it pleasing that a triquetra that will permit the construction of a Celtic Knot can use the Golden Ratio in calculating the width of the lune. The aesthetics of the "Golden Ratio Celtic Knot" are also attractive, although this is subjective.

Comment: I posed the same question in Quora, and I got this answer from Adrian Giles: https://www.quora.com/How-could-you-construct-two-equal-overlapping-circles-such-that-the-lune-overlapping-area-is-equal-in-area-to-the-two-non-overlapsing-regions

θ-sinθ=2π/3

Wolfram Alpha gives the (principal) solution as

θ≈2.60633 radians (≈149.274°) this corresponds to C/(2R)≈0.9643 meaning the distance between centres is ≈ 2√(1–0.9643²)

≈2(0.2649)≈0.5298 (relative to the radius).